# Scripting issue with controlling player in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics

I am creating a simple 2nd game to learn Unity. I have a script that moves the player left and right on the x axis. Also, I have added mobile tilt controls in the same script. However, I have an issue. When I play the game and press the D key to move the player right, it moves right, but as soon as I let go it jumps back 1/2 way. I've spent hours looking at this code, but the player keeps jumping back to about 1/2 way on the x axis. Why is that? Please help, thank you so much!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public class BoundaryOne 
{
public float xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
}

public class Done_PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed;
public BoundaryOne boundary;



void Update ()

    {
        transform.Translate(Input.acceleration.x / 4, 0, 0);
    }
   // void Start ()

//{
    //GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = transform.right * speed;
//}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");


    Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal,0);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = movement * speed;

    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position = new Vector3
    (
        Mathf.Clamp (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax),

        Mathf.Clamp (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position.y, boundary.yMin, boundary.yMax)
    );


}
}
```

Comment: First of all move your controlling code to `Update` instead of `FixedUpdate`. Getting input in FixedUpdate may cause laggy behavior. Second thing you are using `GetComponent` in gameloop which is not a good practice. Take `Rigidbody` in a variable in start and use that. And final thing I want to ask that you are developing 2D game and using 3D components like `Rigidbody` instead of `Rigidbody2D`?

Comment: Yes I'm using the 3D components in 2D game. Check my answer below for new code. I just don't see what is making the player object jump back part way! And the controls do work better after moving to Update, they used to lag a bit.

Comment: You should not give answer like this, you should edit your question instead

Comment: Why are you changing velocity and moving position manually at the same time?

Comment: I thought to move something I needed velocity let me look... I'm pretty new to scripting :(

Comment: I commented the line with velocity and the object couldn't move so I think we need to leave that...

Comment: Can you post a snap of your problem like player should be here but it is not. Or something like that?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I eventually was able to fix it by using AddForce

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public class BoundaryOne 
{
public float xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
}

public class Done_PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed;

//using mathf to limit bounds of movement
public BoundaryOne boundary;



void Update ()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");


    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = movement * speed;

    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position = new Vector3
    (
        Mathf.Clamp(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax),

            Mathf.Clamp(0, 0, 0)
        );
    //my mobile tilt controls

    transform.Translate(Input.acceleration.x / 4, 0, 0);

}

// void Start ()

//{
//GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = transform.right * speed;
//}

}
```